# getting fewer solutions with more opportunities in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

My planning variable is combinations of 4 vehicle runs (routes) that can be performed by a single vehicle.  The individual runs are the planning entity. The goal is to find the maximum number of fully loaded routes where a vehicle performs all runs on the route.  A run can only be associated with a single route.  A hard constraints ensures that a run lands on a route that includes the particular run.

My issue is that it appears that I get a reasonable solution when using a smaller number of routes (300), but when the number routes increases to 30,000 the number of routes decreases instead of increasing.  It should increase because there are significantly more possibilities.

For scoring, I’m minimizing the number routes associated with runs, thus maximizing the number of runs on fewest number of routes.  Other scores minimize/balance route slack and travel times - this rule worked for me elsewhere.  I'm using default move and swap.

Comment: Which meta-heuristics are you using? Tabu search maybe? It is difficult to know what happens in your case, but once, in a particular balancing problems we found out that only Simulated Annealing was providing good enough solutions when increasing the size of the input. Instead, other meta-heuristics like Tabu search seemed to performed better in small size problems. This was due to the fact that Tabu search get stuck in local optimal solutions.

Comment: I'm using tabu search, but I think that the problem is that assigning runs among routes is the issue, especially because all four need to align to form a full route.

Comment: Adding a swap and move filters improved the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you go above 10K customers, a normal VRP implementation won't do. For example, to keep the real distances between 20K customers in RAM memory, you 'd need a 2 dimensional array of 32 bit integers of lengths 20K and 20K. That amounts to almost 2GB RAM. And it doesn't scale linearly.

And in a USA VRP, it's probably useless to connect Boston to San Diego. So performance is problematic too.

For this reason, I am going to add an example with 100K customers in OptaPlanner 6.2 (coming soon), and solve it by limiting Boston to connect to the cities near it (it's a bit more complex than that, but that's the gist of it). If you need something in the next couple of weeks, I suggest to look into the geo-fencing approach as described in the article on [the testimonial page](http://www.optaplanner.org/learn/testimonialsAndCaseStudies.html). Note that my approach will be somewhat different than geo-fencing and there's no proof yet which is better (but I believe mine is of course ;).

Comment: Ah, well I modeled the problem similar to cloudbalancing and prepared all of the possible pairings as the planning variable - it was quite simple.  No VRP here.  It was a matter of just figuring the combination of runs and routes that will maximize the number of routes with two runs.  It was amazing to watch the number of paired routes grow as the slack and travel time were squeezed out.  Slack and travel were attributes of a route.  I used a negative square of the slack, same for travel time.  My understanding is that this has the effect of minimizing and balancing (fairness).

Comment: Ah, interesting approach, possible in this particular use case :) Yes, on squaring creates fairness (see docs on that).

Comment: @user2952819 Do you think your approach could work in a normal VRP use case too? So avoid the chaining all together? And would it scale? I originally dismissed non-chaining approaches on VRP due to scaling issues.

Comment: I don't believe that it will scale. But you gave me something to think about. When time windows come into play, fairness rule for slack and then travel time (in that order) should steer the optimizer in a good direction. –